# Determine channel of wireless interface

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

I know that [`iwconfig`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iwconfig) can provide the frequency of a Wi-Fi interface.

But is there a way to know the channel which was configured for the wireless interface?

I use Ubuntu 12.04.1.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OK, I found an answer:

```
iwlist wlan0 channel
```

Last line of the output informs about the current channel.

Answer (score 10):

Because `iwlist` is deprecated on many systems, you can find the channel using the newer `iw` as well using `iw dev`.

Comment: For instance: `iw wlan0 info`

Comment: I don't see any channels when I run that

Answer (score 1):

**In order to view channels of available wireless interfaces in your locale, you could do:**

1. `airmon-ng start` and view name of wireless interface eg: wlan0
2. `airmon-ng start wlan0`
   (To Put Wi-Fi Adapter in Monitor Mode with Airmon-Ng)
3. `airodump-ng mon0` 
   (Capture Traffic with Airodump-Ng)
4. `airmon-ng stop mon0`
   (To stop Monitor Mode)

**There you will see channels of respective wireless interfaces under heading CH .**

Besides : values `wlan0` and `mon0` may differ depending upon your wireless and monitor mode interface as `wlp2s0` and `wlp2s0mon`.

Comment: If you're going to suggest using tools that need an install you should include install instructions. But a better answer will use tools that are already installed by default.

Answer (score 1):

## Using [`iw`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/iw.8)

Expanding on [confused00's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/485588/determine-channel-of-wireless-interface#1383144) and the helpful comment by [Gabriel Devillers](https://superuser.com/users/585744/gabriel-devillers), `iw wlp3s0 info` prints the currently used channel among other information:

```
ifindex 4
wdev 0x1
addr 78:f9:d4:fa:98:0b
type managed
wiphy 0
channel 11 (2462 MHz), width: 20 MHz, center1: 2462 MHz
txpower 20.00 dBm
```

In this example, `wlp3s0` is the name of the network interface.

Alternatively, `iw wlp3s0 link` shows the frequency in use, 2462 MHz:

```
Connected to d1:81:cb:6a:36:8c (on wlp3s0)
        SSID: Your_Routers_SSID
        freq: 2462
        RX: 809691 bytes (6101 packets)
        TX: 39608 bytes (313 packets)
        signal: -58 dBm
        rx bitrate: 24.0 MBit/s
        tx bitrate: 72.2 MBit/s MCS 7 short GI

        bss flags:  short-preamble short-slot-time
        dtim period:    3
        beacon int: 100
```

`iw phy` gets the supported frequencies:

```
2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
2467 MHz [12] (20.0 dBm)
2472 MHz [13] (20.0 dBm)
2484 MHz [14] (disabled)
```

To print the hardware capabilities of your network controller and the kernel module it uses, run `sudo lspci -vv -s 03:00.0`.

Comment: On my MacBook Pro `iw info` is mostly worthless printing almost nothing. `iw link` will print the frequency used. This can be combined with `iw phy` to determine used channel. Nothing seems to display 802.11 mode (A/G/N/AC/AX).